# Billing address WooCommerce database table

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, user-data, database-table

I would like to know, what database table is WooCommerce using for the Billing Address for each user?

I really need to know, because I need to import users from another database. 
Thanks.

Comment: table usermeta, connecting user_id to db table users...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table used for customers billing address is `'usermeta'`.

To import users from an other database, you need the data from `'users'` and `'usermeta'` tables…

Answer (score 2):

It's actually `wp_postmeta`. Just filter required order ID in `post_id` column.